# How to remove some columns from Datarow.ItemArray

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, datarow

```
IEnumerable<string> fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString());
sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
```

From the above code, I am getting this output

```
#,1104,466161,1,,AUD,190910,876.65,,SO,NOW,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
D,,,,,,,OUT,,,,AUD,,,,0,,0,N,,,,,,
```

But my expected output is

```
#,1104,466161,1,,AUD,190910,876.65,,SO,NOW,,,,,
D,,,,,,,OUT,,,,AUD,,,,0,,0,N,,,,,,
```

want to remove some commas after 'NOW' in the first row

[image]

Comment: How does someone define which items to remove? For example, must be removed items with indexes from `n` to `m`. May be it would be better to work with columns and remove items by their column name, for example, remove items for columns `C5`, `C6`, `C7` and `C8`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way you can delete all trailing commas:

```
var fields = row.ItemArray;
sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields).TrimEnd(','));
```

---

This way you can take a certain number of columns:

```
var fields = row.ItemArray.Take(10);
sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
```